# Как в VS в c# добавить библиотеку во все проекты в решении?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, библиотеки

Есть решение, состоящие из 40 проектов, нужно к каждому из этих проектов подключить библиотеку. Подскажите, есть ли какой то простой способ сделать это, что бы не добавлять по отдельности ссылки на библиотеку в каждый проект?
Идеальные всего было бы положить эту библиотеку к стандартным, что бы в любом проекте можно было подключать ее так же, как например "system"

Comment: Вы можете легко создать из проекта свой собственный шаблон и подключать его.

Comment: Но если проекты уже созданы, то скорее будет добавить ссылку в 40 проектов, чем дождаться хитрого решения здесь.

Comment: Да, проекты уже созданы, и в них скриптом добавляться новые функции, которые описаны как раз в библиотеке. А подключать по отдельности уже надоело, т. к. проходиться делать это чуть ли не каждый день. Мне все таки кажется, что это реально и не сложно сделать, но должными знаниями в C# я не обладаю.

Comment: Тут знания скорее не C#, а средств автоматизации Visual Studio. Если хотите быстрый хак, можно скриптом отредактировать `*.csproj` (там простой XML). Но я бы всё же подождал более человеческое решение.

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю в ожидании ответа, отличное временное решение.

Comment: @VladD, в GAC положить?

Answer (score 1):

Можно осуществить с помощью менеджера пакетов nuget, путем добавления в локальный репозиторий собственной библиотеки.

Comment: Интересный трюк. А его (nuget) можно попросить добавить во _все_ проекты?

Comment: get-project -all | ? { $_.Type -eq 'C#' } | % { $_.Object.References.Add("C:\ProjectPath\Libs\SomeAssembly.dll").Version }

Comment: а если сборка стандартная, то get-project -all | ? { $_.Type -eq 'C#' } | % { $_.Object.References.Add("System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a").Version }

Comment: Ого, круто, тянет на отдельный ответ. А откуда запускать?

Comment: Из консоли nuget?